# How to use a rule correctly in Prolog

Tags: syntax, prolog, rules

I have begun on a short journey of trying to understand how Prolog works, I need some help trying to figure out how to approach a problem and what my code is actually doing. I want to build a sentence from prolog and just as a super basic example that doesn't make much sense I want to compose a sentence like `'you are'` and `'you art'`. 
These are the predicates I have:

```
line(you,[first, type]).
line(thee,[first,old]).
line(thou,[first, new]).

line(are, [second, word]).
line(art, [second, word]).
line(aurt, [second, place]).
```

Then I created a rule (which I know is wrong but I don't know why):

```
line(A, [composed, type]):-
    line(B, [first, type]),
    line(C, [second, word]),
    append([B,C],A).
```

Typing into commandline:

```
?- line(A, [composed, type]).
false.
```

But what is not intuitive to me is that typing something like:

```
?- line(A, [first,type]).
A = you ;
false.

?- line(A, [second,word]).
A = are ;
A = art ;
false.
```

Give me the words I want. Can someone please help me better understand the way I should compose a rule such that my **expected** result is something like:

```
findall(X, line(X, [composed, type]),Y).
Y= you are;
Y= you art;
false.
```

I hope this makes a little sense and I didn't completely mess up the Prolog syntax in that last block of code. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you know unification?

Comment: @GuyCoder after a quick google search I get the super basic idea that it's as the name implying, unifying two atoms or or terms? and what am I missing in terms of getting an expected result in the last block of code?

Comment: The point of the question was to see if you knew unification. While I thank you for being honest in saying you had to look it up, it tells us that you the distance between what you know and what you need to know is more than a simple answer. You need to learn unification, then backward chaining to start.

Comment: thank you @GuyCoder for the quick reply, I will make sure to read up on them in detail

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to show you the proper way to approach this problem, which is with DCGs:

```
sentence --> noun, verb.
noun --> [you].
verb --> [are].
verb --> [art].
```

Now you can generate sentences simply by using the DCG driver `phrase/2`:

```
?- phrase(sentence, X).
X = [you, are] ;
X = [you, art].
```

What you have up there, with `[first, type]` and `[second, word]`, I am having some trouble understanding. But DCGs are a great way to do light NLP tasks like this.

Comment: Thank you, although when I type `sentence --> noun, verb` I get a warning of: `Correct to: "sentence*->noun, verb"?`, am I missing something before that?

Comment: @jaleman make sure you have already typed `[user].` and are looking at the prompt for new rules. Or put this in a file and consult it.

Comment: thank you so much! You have taught me more Prolog than my professors :/